# Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path } NameError: undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm currently working through chapter seven of Rails Tutorial and seem to be stuck at figure 7.22. In brief, I'm unable to get the tests to pass. When I run . . .

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
```

. . . I see a bunch of failed tests that read:

```
 Failures:

1) User pages signup page 
    Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
    NameError:
    undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for # <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fb2be028410>
 # ./user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages signup page 
   Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
   NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fb2be048ad0>
 # ./user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) User pages signup page with invalid information should not create a user
   Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
   NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fb2be062e80>
 # ./user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) User pages signup page with valid information should create a user
   Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
   NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fb2be083158>
 # ./user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00374 seconds
4 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages signup page with invalid information should not create a user
rspec ./user_pages_spec.rb:32 # User pages signup page with valid information should create a user

Randomized with seed 10291
```

I'm guessing the main error involves the undefined method or varialble "signup_path," but I have no clue whatsoever where it's supposed to be defined or whether it should have at some point automatically been defined by Rails in the first place.

Could someone help me with this?

UPDATE: Below is my routes file.

Thanks for your reply. Here's my routes file. Unless I'm missing something, everything seems OK to me:

```
SecondSampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "users/new"
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/about"

  resources :users

  root "static_pages#home"

  match "/signup",  to: "users#new",            via: "get"
  match "/help",    to: "static_pages#help",    via: "get"
  match "/about",   to: "static_pages#about",   via: "get"
  match "/contact", to: "static_pages#contact", via: "get"


end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'


Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }


ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|


config.include Capybara::DSL

config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

config.order = "random"

config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Here are the failing tests in user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "signup page" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }


    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

        before do
            fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end

describe "profile page" do 

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before {visit user_path(user)}
    it {should have_content(user.name)}
    it {should have_title(user.name)}
end

end
```

Comment: add your spec_helper.rb code. and check if `rake routes` output has route signup.

Comment: spec_helper.rb has been posted above. I can't seem to run rake routes successfully; when I try, I receive an error that reads: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `routes' for main:Object."

Answer (score 2):

When going through the Hartl tutorial and you encounter an `undefined local variable or method` error or otherwise want to find out what the current definition of a variable or method is supposed to be at that point in the tutorial, the following technique is helpful:

- Go to the book on the web
- Click the "view as single page" link in the upper right hand corner
- With the browser's search command, search backwards from where you are in the tutorial for variable/method name in question. (Note: If there are lots of them, and you're sure it's a method, you can narrow the search to "def variable_or_method_in_question")
- Note the definition and the file in which the definition occurs (typically given in the header of the table/listing/figure)

Going to the github repository is helpful sometimes as well, but that shows the *final* state/location of the code, which can often be misleading.

In your case, this technique results in finding an entry in [Table 5.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#table-url_mapping) which indicates that this variable is a path generated by Rails as a result of the contents of your `routes.rb` file. You should check the contents of that file and look at the currently defined routes using `rake routes` on the command line.

Comment: When I run rake routes, here's what I get an error that reads: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `routes' for main:Object."

Comment: Ok, well the good news is that this explains your test failure. :-)

Comment: HALP! I don't understand.

Comment: What's the last successful test you ran in the Hartl tutorial?

Comment: Whatever the last test was in the previous chapter (six), I believe.

Comment: Hmmm. Why don't you try `rake --trace routes`

Comment: Okay. Thanks for bearing with me, Peter. When you told me to try running rake routes via Rails' console, I was literally going into Rails console ("rails c"), which explains why I couldn't get the command to run. There seem to be two discrete routes associated with the users#new controller action--"signup GET    /signup(.:format)             users#new" and "new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          users#new". I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Would you post your failing test?

Comment: No problem. I've posted them in the original post.

Comment: Ok, try entering the following in the Rails console: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.signup_path`

Comment: I get this:  => "/signup"

Comment: Ok, I'm really not sure what's going on, since comparable tests passed for you at the end of chapter 6. Do any of your tests involving paths work?

Comment: The answer for this question got two of my four tests to pass: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. What versions of `rspec` and `rspec-rails` are you running? Which tests are succeeding and which are failing with that addition? Is there a common denominator?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852683/why-cant-i-access-rails-url-helpers-from-my-rspec-tests, for example.

Comment: Now, three of the four tests are passing, and the fourth isn't supposed to pass yet because I'm not that far in the tutorial. The two "signup_path"-related tests succeeded after I included a reference to the url helpers within spec_helpers.rb. The "full_title" test succeeded after I added support/utilities.rb and created a full_title method. I only have rspec-rails (gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'), not gems for both rspec and rspec-rails.

Comment: Are you using the exact Gemfile that Hartl specifies in http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-gemfile_rspec or the later version in 9.47? As I said, that configuration statement shouldn't be required.

Comment: I'm using the one from earlier in the book. I'm not sure what the deal is with the configuration statement.

Comment: Perhaps rspec-rails is not getting loaded? Want to share your `spec_helper.rb` file?

Comment: Sorry. I've run out of ideas. I believe it really should be including those helpers without you having to do so explicitly.  I found https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/476, but it doesn't look like it applies to you. If you ever figure this out, please let me know. Again, sorry I couldn't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

This nolonger applies to the tutorial by Michael Hartl http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Spork is not being used in tutorial for Rails 4 now, this may change, I followed the page linked below but it will overwrite the existing spec setup and install Gems not required by the tutorial.

Are you using Spork? If so you have to restart it any time you make changes in routes.rb.

Described in Listing 3.38:

> One word of advice when using Spork: after changing a file included in the prefork loading (such as routes.rb), you will have to restart the Spork server to load the new Rails environment. If your tests are failing when you think they should be passing, quit the Spork server with Ctrl-C and restart it.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-spork

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 add code to rails_helper.rb :
`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`